# Google Cloud IoT sendCommandToDevice from cloud funcctions showing Service Unavailable

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-iot

I tried sending the command from cloud functions, I am  getting Error: The service is currently unavailable.

Package.JSON
"dependencies": {
    "firebase-admin": "~6.0.0",
    "firebase-functions": "^2.0.3",
    "googleapis": "34.0.0"
  }

```
const parentName = `projects/${projectId}/locations/${cloudRegion}`;
const registryName = `${parentName}/registries/${reqData.registryId}`;
const binaryData = Buffer.from(JSON.stringify(reqData.message)).toString('base64');
const request = {
    name: `${registryName}/devices/${reqData.deviceId}`,
    binaryData: binaryData
};

google.auth.getClient().then((authClient) => {
    const discoveryUrl =
        `${DISCOVERY_API}?version=${API_VERSION}`;
    if (authClient.createScopedRequired && authClient.createScopedRequired()) {
      // Scopes can be specified either as an array or as a single,
      // space-delimited string.
      authClient = authClient.createScoped([
        'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform'
      ]);
    }

    google.options({
      auth: authClient
    });

    google.discoverAPI(discoveryUrl).then((client, err) => {
      if (err) {
        console.log('Error during API discovery', err);
        return undefined;
      }
      client.projects.locations.registries.devices.sendCommandToDevice(request,
        (err, data) => {
          if (err) {
            console.log('Could not send command:', request);
            console.log('Message: ', err);
          } else {
            console.log('Success :', data.statusText);
          }
        });
    });
  });
```

Logs:
{ Error: The service is currently unavailable. at createError (/user_code/node_modules/googleapis/node_modules/axios/lib/core/createError.js:16:15) at settle (/user_code/node_modules/googleapis/node_modules/axios/lib/core/settle.js:18:12) at Unzip.handleStreamEnd (/user_code/node_modules/googleapis/node_modules/axios/lib/adapters/http.js:201:11) at emitNone (events.js:91:20) at Unzip.emit (events.js:185:7) at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:974:12) at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:80:11) at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:128:9)

Comment: I'm having this same error and nobody seems to know why ... UGH

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that `subfolder` **MUST** be specified, and **MUST** not be an empty string.

As I was using this in a Firebase function, I just use the `firebase` subfolder for any commands being sent that do not have a specific subfolder

```
const request = {
    name: `${registryName}/devices/${deviceId}`,
    binaryData: Buffer.from(JSON.stringify(commandMessage)).toString("base64"),
    subfolder: 'firebase'
}
```

Here's functions deps:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "firebase-admin": "^6.4.0",
    "firebase-functions": "^2.1.0",
    "fs-extra": "^7.0.0",
    "googleapis": "^36.0.0",
  },
```

This is probably due to

1. bug in the node library
2. bug in Google's endpoint
3. Lack of testing on Google's part

Seems that Google's "IoT" is still very young and needs a lot of work

Comment: What's really strange is that I'm unable to reproduce this behavior on my machine running locally with Node which leads me to believe this is specific to GCF.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not too familiar with Firebase cloud functions, but I didn't get the error using the inline editor for Cloud Functions (https://console.cloud.google.com/functions). Can you tell me when you started getting this error (and if you're still encountering it)?

For reference, here was the code that I used (basically what you had but with more explicit definitions for `projectId, cloudRegion`.

```
const {google} = require('googleapis');

const API_VERSION = 'v1';
const DISCOVERY_API = 'https://cloudiot.googleapis.com/$discovery/rest';

exports.sendCommand = (req, res) => {
  let reqData = req.body;

  const projectId = reqData.projectId || process.env.GCLOUD_PROJECT;
  const cloudRegion = reqData.cloudRegion || process.env.GCLOUD_REGION;

  const parentName = `projects/${projectId}/locations/${cloudRegion}`;
  const registryName = `${parentName}/registries/${reqData.registryId}`;
  const binaryData = Buffer.from(JSON.stringify(reqData.message)).toString('base64');
  const request = {
      name: `${registryName}/devices/${reqData.deviceId}`,
      binaryData: binaryData
  };

  google.auth.getClient().then((authClient) => {
      const discoveryUrl =
          `${DISCOVERY_API}?version=${API_VERSION}`;
      if (authClient.createScopedRequired && authClient.createScopedRequired()) {
        // Scopes can be specified either as an array or as a single,
        // space-delimited string.
        authClient = authClient.createScoped([
          'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform'
        ]);
      }

      google.options({
        auth: authClient
      });

      google.discoverAPI(discoveryUrl).then((client, err) => {
        if (err) {
          console.log('Error during API discovery', err);
          return undefined;
        }
        client.projects.locations.registries.devices.sendCommandToDevice(request,
          (err, data) => {
            if (err) {
              console.log('Could not send command:', request);
              console.log('Message: ', err);
            } else {
              console.log('Success :', data.statusText);
            }
          });
      });
    });
  res.status(200).send(reqData.message);
};
```